I was creating a build of my expo app for testing and during build this error is coming so can anybody guide me how to fix this
Running 'gradlew :app:bundleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Welcome to Gradle 8.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:

Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
Build init improvements
Build authoring improvements
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build

Configure project :
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
Task :gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
Task :gradle-plugin:classes
Task :gradle-plugin:jar
FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
1: Task failed with an exception.


Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-autolinking/scripts/android/autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 408
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.

A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-sensors'.
Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
2: Task failed with an exception.


Where:
Script '/home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-modules-core/android/ExpoModulesCorePlugin.gradle' line: 85
What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.


Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponent container of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.


Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2m 5s
5 actionable tasks: 5 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

I tried diffrent methods on internet but didn't work.
This is my package.json
{
  "name": "faizan-e-chisht",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.7.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "expo": "^51.0.22",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "^12.0.9",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "^13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-location": "~17.0.1",
    "expo-notifications": "^0.28.11",
    "expo-permissions": "^14.4.0",
    "expo-router": "^3.5.18",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "lpf": "^1.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "moment-hijri": "^2.1.2",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-qibla-compass": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.3.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

This is my eas.json
{
"build": {
"preview": {
  "android": {
    "buildType": "apk"
  }
},
"preview2": {
  "android": {
    "gradleCommand": ":app:assembleRelease"
  }
},
"preview3": {
  "developmentClient": true
},
"production": {}
}
}

